# Is the console command cd a wildcard of sorts?

Tags: command-line

I was wondering while developing some application (though this is not a development question) if the `cd` command used in Windows is a wildcard or cross-platform command of sorts. I looked up on table with comands for Unix/Linux and MAC OS X and it turns out that it seems to be there. I am not a multi-os user, so I ask if anyone with experience in different OSes can tell me:

1. If this command really exists and works
2. If it has the same functionality (change directory)
3. If there are any problems with its use
4. If in any OS there is another command-line command that does the same in a better/more elaborate/more frequetly used way.

Thanks in advance!

(P.S.I am not 100% sure if this question belongs to this site or some other stackexchange site...)

(P.P.S Any help in tagging this will be appreciated!)

Comment: VMS uses `SET DEFAULT` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If this command really exists and works

Um, yes, it exists and works.

> If it has the same functionality (change directory)

Yes; yes it does. That’s not to say that someone could not simply create a program (e.g., `cd.exe`) that does something else, but it is usually a command built into the shell and changes the current directory.

> If there are any problems with its use

What kind of problems? Other than `.` and `..`, its syntax is quite straight forward. The only complication is when changing the current directory on other volumes (drive letters). Also, the command-extensions in Windows extend its usage slightly, but nothing that would cause any real problems.

> If in any OS there is another command-line command that does the same in a better/more elaborate/more frequetly used way.

Not really. There can be other commands, but `cd` is nice and short and does the trick. Other than changing the current drive in addition to the directory, (e.g., `cd /d t:\blah`), how exactly could changing the current directory be improved?

---

This isn’t quite on-topic (though it is related), but apparently some people can’t seem to accept that the `CD` command does not *have* to be built into the shell. The fact is that it does **not**; it *can* be an external program. Some operating systems make it easy, others make it difficult, and some may even make it impossible, but the fact is that it *can* be external and does not *always have to be built in* as some would have you believe. For example, on 32-bit versions of Windows including XP and 7, you can make use of the fact that the console subsystem (which is how text-mode programs are supported and run in Windows) supports the old “DOS” interrupt 0x21—yes, even in `cmd`, not just `command. (It will not work in 64-bit versions of Windows because they dropped a lot of backward-compatibility.)

For example, you can save the debug script below as `c.scr` and compile it by running `debug < c.scr` from the command-line. It will create a `.com` file which you can use to change the current directory.

```
a
mov si,82
mov dl,[si]
or dl,20
sub dl,61
mov ah,e
int 21
mov dl,[si]
cmp dl,d
jz 119
inc si
jmp 10f
xor dl,dl
mov [si],dl
mov dx,82
mov ah,3b
int 21
mov ah,4c
int 21

n c.com
rcx
28
w
q
```

(Note, it does not support long filenames, so you will need to use the [8.3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename) version. It changes the current drive as well, so you can change the directory to another drive in one move, but it does this in a very simple manner and does not do any error-checking, so trying to change to a directory which starts with a letter for which a drive exists will not work. That is, `c c:\windows` will work as will `c \windows`, but `c asd` will not if you have an `A:` drive unless it happens to contain a directory named `asd`. You can extend it and add error-checking and such if you like, but it proves my point about the possibility of `cd` being external in Windows.)

You can also save the following Pascal program (e.g., as `c.pas`) and compile it with Turbo Pascal or the GO32 version of the FreePascal compiler (the 32-bit version won’t work because it uses the normal Windows API):

```
program cd;
begin
  chdir(paramstr(1));
end.
```

Again, just run it to change the current directory (e.g., `c.exe "c:\program files"—yes, long foldernames will work, but will be automatically converted to 8.3 names upon execution).

Comment: Even though some other may put more time to write their replies, yours is most straitforward and to my points, therefore I choose this as the answer! Thanks a lot for the help! :)

Comment: No problem; glad to help. I usually try to address the question asked even if it’s not completely clear.

Comment: `cd` must be built into the shell on both Unix/Linux and Windows systems because the current directory is part of the process state and is inherited from parent to child, not the other way.  If you spawn a child process, it inherits its parent's current directory.  But the child can then change its current directory without affecting the parent.  This is why a separate `cd.exe` command would do nothing.

Comment: @NicoleHamilton you seem to know quite a bit about the matter and I think you may be able to help me out: Can you explain the way to get to the parent folder in both Unix and Windows? I have seen the cd . and cd .. in some replies. Can you give me a small help with this because I am developing a small application that needs to have this functionality...

Comment: `.` is the current directory.  `..` is the parent.  So to go up one directory, use `cd ..`

Comment: @NicoleHamilton, when I referred to a `cd.exe`, I was not talking about directors, I said it could do something else, as in it could be a text editor, calculate π, or display a 4KB demo. And it *would* do something if you executed it. If you run just `cd`, then it would use the built-in version, but if you ran `cd.exe`, it would run the external one.

Comment: @Spiritios, you are writing a program and yet are not familiar with a basic command like [`cd`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cd_(command))? `o.O` What are you programming in? Unless you mean you are writing a batch-file, then you probably won’t be using the `cd` command or `..` and will need to use a different mechanism and syntax altogether.

Comment: @Synetech:  I was responding to where you said, "it is usually a command built into the shell".  If you want a `cd` command that can actually change your current directory, it not merely usually builtin.  It always is.  It has to be in order for it to work.  Hope that helps.

Comment: @NicoleHamilton, huh? I don’t see why it would *have* to be built-in. You could write an external program that simply calls `INT 21h; AH 3Bh`. I would think that someone who wrote their own compiler would know that.

Comment: @NicoleHamilton, I doubt that `cd ..` would be of much use in a program unless he is to use the dreaded `system` command.

Comment: @Synetech, `cd` can't be an external program on any OS that supports a process model, which includes both Linux and Windows (Win32).  `INT 21h` is an old DOS interrupt; DOS did not support a process model.  No one in their right mind would write ASM programs for DOS that called `INT 21h` today.

Comment: I am writing in Java btw and I simulate a console so I just wanted to simulate this command in my project and wanted to know if it is OS-dependent, but as I see the differences are quite minor, so I can easily use calls to the built-in cd command for my task! :)

Comment: *> INT 21h is an old DOS interrupt*   @NicoleHamilton, that is entirely beside the point. The console subsystem supports INT 21, so the statement that the `cd` command *must* be built into the shell on Windows is incorrect.

Comment: @Spiritios, if you are *creating* your own command-prompt, then you can do whatever you want. If you are simply making calls to system commands, e.g. `system("cd", …)`, (which for security reasons is [highly inadvisable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection)), then it won’t matter because yes, the `cd` command generally behaves the same across most platforms.

Comment: Yes found it out myself, so I will sort it out by writing my own cd command for my application so that I have better control and save myself from the security problems. Practically this thread was of no use to anybody, but still I now have a very good outine on how to make my cd command the right way! :)

Comment: @Spiritios, I’m glad you have what you need and have [security](http://security.stackexchange.com/) in mind. Java is already designed to be saf *er* than running native code, but it’s always better to be wary when taking any input from users.

Comment: Yeah also I have in mind developing a very lightweight console-based solely Java-based distro with a team later on for some programming purposes and thought I will have my cd already redefined and not dependent on the underlying OS which will help me have less code to modify when if ever that project gets started, so really your suggestion came just about the right moment that I was reconsidering!

Comment: Great; glad to help. In fact, if you make calls to the API to set the current directory instead of to the shell command, then you will be better off.

Comment: @Synetech, Windows supports a DOS box.  But if you run a DOS program from `cmd.exe` (or any other Win32 program) that changes the current directory using an `INT 21h` call, it will NOT change the current directory of the parent process.  So this is NOT beside the point.  On any system that supports a process model, the current directory is part of the process state and can only be changed inside the process.  That's necessary because if the current directory could be changed by another process, relative paths would be unreliable; you'd never know what file you might get.

Comment: *> it will NOT change the current directory of the parent process.*   You mean Explorer (or whatever process spawned `cmd`)? Of course not! Why would you want to do that anyway? It would be silly and wrong. You only want the current instance of `cmd` (the one that you are actually working in) to change.

Comment: *> Windows supports a DOS box. But if you run a DOS program from cmd.exe (or any other Win32 program) that changes the current directory using an INT 21h call, it will NOT change the current directory of the parent process.*   @NicoleHamilton, if by “DOS box”, you mean the console subsystem and/or the NTVDM, then yes, yes it does. Either way, you are incorrect. I threw together a 40-byte assembler (`.com`) program that uses `3B, INT 21` and it works **perfectly** in 32-bit XP and 7 and I am sure that it’s possible to write a 32-bit `.exe` version that works in 64-bit Windows as well.

Comment: Prove it.  Send it to me at hamilton@hamiltonlabs.com.

Comment: *> Prove it.*   @NicoleHamilton, DONE. (See above.)

Comment: It's not in my inbasket nor my spam filters.  Did you get a bounce, perhaps from a typo?  Can you try again, please?

Comment: Your `c.com` program only works with `cmd.exe` and only because `cmd.exe` special cases DOS children, examining the state of the NTVDM when  the child exits and then setting its own current directory to match that of the child at exit.  It does not work in the general case of a Win32 program starting the child with CreateProcess.  I've edited your answer to add a toy program example showing that but it hasn't been made visible (yet).  If for some reason my edit doesn't appear and you'd like to see it, please contact me offline.

Comment: @NicoleHamilton, it seems your edit was rejected, and rightfully so because it is meaningless. You said the `cd` command *must* be built into the shell in all cases, and I clearly showed it does not. You nag it’s because of the NTVDM, but that just proves what I said: it **is** possible for *change-current-directory* to be external.   *> It does not work in the general case of a Win32 program starting the child with CreateProcess.*   What does that have to do with *anything*‽ Why would you even want to do it that way‽ What sane programmer would have their program call the shell’s `cd` command?

Comment: @Syntech, the reason your `c.com` works is because the actual change directory is done by `cmd.exe` after it examines the NTVDM, not by the child.  That's built into `cmd.exe`, not external.  In any OS that supports a process model (do you even know what that is?  It doesn't appear so!) you cannot change another process's current directory because it would make filesystem calls unreliable.  A process on Windows or Linux or any other OS that supports a process model can only change its own current directory.  I don't how to be more clear.

Comment: @NicoleHamilton, it works in both `cmd.exe` and `command.com`. Either way, DOS is being emulated, so `c.com` running in an emulated DOS is no different than running it in real DOS. Either way, it is *working*. Your nitpicks are pointless. You said it cannot be done, but it can. The argument isn’t how it is implemented, just whether it is at all possible, which it is. The specific mechanics of *how* it works is irrelevant because the fact is that it **does work** contrary to your claim. I don’t know how to be more clear.

Answer (score 5):

The idea of a `cd` change directory command was invented as part of Unix in 1969.  It's terse, like most of the other Unix commands like `ls`, `rm`, `sed` and so on.  It also matched the tree-structured filesystem invented as part of Unix, where even devices were files under `/dev`.  It's easy to forget that before Unix, there weren't many OSes that had tree-structured filesystems with directories that ordinary users could easily create.  Usually, you just got (at best) a pile of files somewhere and strange IBM utilities like IEBGENER to manipulate it.

What `cd` does is change the current directory of the current process, in this case, the shell, which affects how the operating system will interpret relative filenames, i.e., those that aren't fully-qualified from the root `/` of the filesystem.  The current directory is inherited from parent to child process.

There are a couple big differences in the semantics of `cd` on Unix or Linux systems versus Windows systems.  One is, what should `cd` with no operand do?  On Unix or Linux, it takes you to the home directory.  On Windows, `cmd.exe`'s `cd` simply reports the current directory.  Also, Windows is not singly-rooted, it has drive letters and you can have a current directory on each one, though the behind-the-scenes implementation is that Microsoft threw that over the wall into application space:  Each process carries some hidden environment variables with strange names like `=C:` that the application is responsible for keeping current.

Some `cd` commands are better than others, but this may be a matter of taste.  The [C shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_shell) introduced the idea of `CDPATH` that works like the `PATH` variable does but finds directories instead of executables.  The C shell also introduced directory stacks allowing you to `pushd` or `popd` the current directory.  In writing [my own C shell](http://hamiltonlabs.com/Cshell.htm) I copied all that, added an option to let the user decide what `cd` with no operand should do and a feature a customer suggested that if you type more than 2 dots, as in `cd ....` it should go up n-1 levels.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `cd` is a *nix command that works on Linux, OSX, and the other *nix OSes.

Answer (score 1):

Just a curiosity: AFAIR, in Novell DOS (quite a few years ago) `cd .` remained in current directory, `cd ..` went to the parent directory, `cd ...` went two levels up in the hierarchy, `cd ....` three levels and so on.

Comment: It wasn’t just Novell DOS either, MS-DOS and the Windows command-prompt behaved like that a few versions ago as well. It’s one of the things I miss most in newer versions of Windows.

Comment: The customer who suggested it to me, probably sometime around 1990, might well have used it in a previous shell.  I know I didn't invent it.

Comment: @NicoleHamilton: well, it is quite an obvious idea, so it is well possible that many people invented it independently.

Answer (score 1):

The `cd` command in DOS and Windows is very similar to that for Unix/Linux, and with good reason: the whole concept of directories was copied from Unix.

The first system to run MS-DOS (branded as PC-DOS) was the IBM PC. There was no hard disk — storage was on floppies, which came in 180K and 360K capacities. With such limited media, you didn't need a complicated file-naming scheme. So a fully-qualified file name was just a drive designator followed by an [8.3 filename](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename) such as `a:autoexec.bat` or `b:advent.exe`.

MS-DOS 2.0 attempted to deal with a lot of issues like this by copying features from Unix. This included directories and the commands for dealing with them. One problem was that MS-DOS was already using the / character to indicate optional arguments; this is why Windows and Unix use different path separator characters.

One important difference is that Unix has a uniform directory hierarchy with no drive designators. In adapting the `cd` command to MS-DOS, Microsoft had to invent new semantics for the notion of "current directory" that takes the drive designator into account. To maximize backward compatibility (so that names like `a:something` would still mean something sensible) they invented the notion of "current drive", and decreed that each drive have its own "current directory". So when you're changing the "current directory" you're really changing the current directory for the current drive. Usually this kind of detail isn't something you have to worrry about. But it does explain why when you're on `c:\somedir` and you do `cd d:\otherdir` nothing seems to happen. What *has* happened is that you've changed the current directory for you `d:` drive without changing your current drive; you have to enter a `d:` command for that to happen.